# DataBase design best practices for connect 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables:

- index(id, asset_id, name, source_id, country_id)
- index_trade_data_daily(index_id, date, daily_return)

*First approach* (current, see the picture below): **id** from index table connected to **index_id** and **date** from index_trade_data_daily. As I know in one to many relationship primary key from one table should be connected to foreign key from another table. But in this kind of relation I have no foreign-key. It's look like one-to-one connection. Where pk in index_trade_data_daily consist from 2 fields. **Is it correct?**
in addition index_trade_data_daily have no **id** and it's confusing me.

*The second approach* is to add **id** to index_trade_data_daily. Generate one-to-many relationship with index table. And add unique constraints both to [**index_id**, **date**].
But in this case **id** has no sense.

Which approach is better ?

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that the relationship is 1:N. Every index may have multiple trade data, one per day.

Comment: "...As I know in one to many relationship primary key from one table should be connected to foreign key from another table..." -- No, what you say is true for "weak entities" only. The `index_trade_data_daily` table seems to be a normal entity per se; but... it's difficult to tell just with the information you provide.

Comment: @TheImpaler As you said before every index may have multiple trade data.

Answer (score 0):

Index table looks fine but the other table should have its own ID for itself as well as the index_FK (foreign key) from the index table which is related to the index ID from the index table.
Note you may want to think about using better names for your tables as the name "index" is apart of a table structure.

Comment: No the child table should NOT blindly be assigned an identity column as the primary key. And I will almost guarantee that the current PK (index_id, date) is a perfect tuple for both primary key and clustered index (though order is an important consideration).